How can I catch an AggregateException? Copilot is telling me to return Task, but I already am
I'm trying to create an AggregateException to observe some behavior. I'm getting en error here: "Cannot await void." I'm not sure why. Copilot is telling me this:

To fix the error "Cannot await 'void'", you need to change the return type of the RunAsync method from void to Task.

As you can see, RunAsync already has a return type of Task. What am I missing?
namespace ThreadingPracticeTime
{
    public class ThreadingPractice
    {
        public async Task RunAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.WaitAll(Method1Async(), Method2Async(), Method3Async());
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                foreach (var e in ae.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"An aggregate error occurred: {e.Message}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"A general error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("done");
        }

        private async Task Method1Async()
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000); // Example delay
            throw new Exception("An error occurred in Method1Async");
        }

        private async Task Method2Async()
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000); // Example delay
        }

        private async Task Method3Async()
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000); // Example delay
            throw new Exception("An error occurred in Method3Async");
        }
    }
}


At what line do you get the warning?

At the first line in RunAsync: await Task.WaitAll(....

Why do you ask Copilot and not just the compiler? Copilot outputs a load of lies. Your issue is you're awaiting the result of Task.WaitAll, which is void. You probably meant Task.WhenAll.

From my research, Task.WhenAll unwraps the aggregate and only throws the first exception. I want the aggregate to examine all of the exceptions.

WhenAll does none of those things.  await will throw the first exception in the aggregate, rather than re-throwing the aggregate exception itself.

@Servy So are you saying there's no way to catch an aggregate exception?

Take a look at this: I want await to throw AggregateException, not just the first Exception.
